# Svelteki api fetch pages

Tags: api, sveltekit

In short, I want to fetch data from diferents pages from one API I've made.

The API is https://joao-back-ecommerce-prod.herokuapp.com/store/ and as you can see I've multiples endpoints.

With svelte i'm trying to go from page to page in one click with increment function.

exemple:

```
<script context="module">
    export async function load({ fetch, page }) {
        const id = page.params.id;
        const res = await fetch(
            `https://joao-back-ecommerce-prod.herokuapp.com/store/products/?page=${id}`
        );
        const products = await res.json();
        console.log(products);

        if (res.ok) {
            return {
                props: {
                    products: products.results
                }
            };
        }
        return {
            status: res.status,
            error: new Error('Could not fetch the results')
        };
    }
</script>

<script>
    export let products;
    export let id = 1;

    const next = () => {
        id++;
    };
</script>

<ul>
    {#each products as product}
        <li>
            {product.title} - {product.description}
            <a href={product.id}>hlmlll</a>
        </li>
    {/each}
    <button on:click={next}>Next</button>
</ul>
```

I want to go to next page when click on button next. I thought that with increment id + 1 it will be work, but, it doesn't.

In the browser when I change the page number it works.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just changing a local variable, it does not affect the url.
What you would do is *navigate* to the next page by changing the url.

There are two ways to do this:

```js
import { goto } from '$app/navigation';
const next = () => goto(`/product/${id+1}`); // change to get correct path for you
```

or, a *better* way is to actually just link to the next page instead:

```html
<a href="/product/{id+1}">Next</a>
```

The second option is preferred because you are in fact navigating for which you should use a link (buttons are for actions), it will also work if the user has javascript disabled.

SvelteKit will not actually go to the server and load a new page, it will just fetch the data from the `load` function and update accordingly, the user will not notice they are on a different page, only the url changes.

Comment: thanks for the quick answer. I've already tried this 2 approachs and none of them really works. For the last one we get stuck in "/products/page1" and when I click "Next" I'm not redirect to "/products/page2".

Comment: What do you mean with 'stuck' ? Does the url change at least ?

Comment: Sorry .. When I mean "stuck" I want to say, that url doesn't change.

Comment: any errors ? and you did make it an anchor tag right ?

Comment: No errors.. yes with a anchor .. <a href="/products/page{id + 1}">Next</a>. If I change the variable id to (for exemple) 2, the anchor will send me to "products/page4", but if click again in "Next" there is no increment.

Comment: oooh, you mean the path of your anchor stays the same ? that is because `id` doesn't actually change, you should return it in the _props_ from the load function: `return { props: { id, product: ... } }`

Comment: Well .. not working with me .. I have no problems to fetch products by id, like "products/2". This is good, and i don't have any problems. The problem is when I try to fetch the "next page" where "products/page{id}" must change with "next" anchor to see the next 10 results.. I must dig further to find out want is wrong.

Comment: Well when `return {props: {id, product: .... }}` url is changing, but from "/products/page1", when I click "next" url goes to "/products/page11" and then ".../page111". This is hard .. ahahah

Comment: I've find a solution for the concatenation problem. `return {props: {id : parseInt(id), products: ....}}` . Thanks for the help.